# S3 presign integrity md5 upload

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to check object upload integrity:

First of all, I generate a presigned url:

```bash
$ aws s3 presign s3://espaidoc/lorem.txt
http://localstack.localhost:8000/espaidoc/lorem.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=test%2F20240307%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240307T144123Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&
X-Amz-Signature=6cfd701cf00549538ab9079b87fd2dbfa6d6750978cd1f616aef98ce077d52f0
```

Then, I first calculate the md5 checksum of file I want to upload:

```bash
$ md5sum hurl/push-document/lorem.txt
1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82  hurl/push-document/lorem.txt
```

Then I `PUT` the file to s3:

```bash
curl --request PUT --header 'content-md5: 1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82' --data-binary '@hurl/push-document/lorem.txt' http://localstack.localhost:8000/espaidoc/lorem.txt\?X-Amz-Algorithm\=AWS
4-HMAC-SHA256\&X-Amz-Credential\=test%2F20240307%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request\&X-Amz-Date\=20240307T144123Z\&X-Amz-Expires\=3600\&X-Amz-SignedHeaders\=host\&X-Amz-Signature=6cfd701cf00549538ab9079b87fd2dbfa6d6750978cd1f
616aef98ce077d52f0
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Error><Code>InvalidDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.</Message><RequestId>ba7ede53-42f1-46cc-97c5-86149c0cf008</RequestId><Content-MD5>1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82</Content-MD5></Error>
```

As you can see, I'm getting `The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.`.

I've also tried with encoding med checksum to base64:

```bash
$ echo "1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82" | base64
MWQxMTQ2OWU5ZDgxZjA3NzI5NTQ4ZDc3MDhiYmFiODIK
```

And I've also tried with:

```bash
curl --request PUT --header 'content-md5: MWQxMTQ2OWU5ZDgxZjA3NzI5NTQ4ZDc3MDhiYmFiODIK' --data-binary '@hurl/push-document/lorem.txt' http://localstack.localhost:8000/espaidoc/lorem.txt\?X-Amz-Al
gorithm\=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\&X-Amz-Credential\=test%2F20240307%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request\&X-Amz-Date\=20240307T144123Z\&X-Amz-Expires\=3600\&X-Amz-SignedHeaders\=host\&X-Amz-Signature=6cfd701cf00549538ab9079b87fd2dbfa6
d6750978cd1f616aef98ce077d52f0
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Error><Code>InvalidDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.</Message><RequestId>6ab43857-d49c-4f2b-8aff-a8a03dea6cc8</RequestId><Content-MD5>MWQxMTQ2OWU5ZDgxZjA3NzI5NTQ4ZDc3MDhiYmFiODIK</Content-MD
5></Error>
```

But I'm getting same message.

Any ideas?

Comment: You generated a pre-signed GET, not a PUT.